# AdColony ad kills my main activity

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, adcolony

I've extended the UnityPlayerActivity to integrate AdColony and Flurry Analytics.
For some reason whenever I show a video ad using AdColony it stops my main activity and kills it. Any idea why this might be happening?

Answer (score 0):

This is an issue requiring individual help, where you will need to provide a full console log showing your app's activity and the errors that you are seeing; please reach out to the AdColony support team at support@adcolony.com.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with my android project. Adcolony called onDestroy() method. I fixed it by changes my AndroidManifest.xml file. There was some problem with android:configChanges.

Was:

```
android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|fontScale|locale"
```

Change to:

```
    android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
```

And it helped me.